# Help in finding the Jordan canonical form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Determine the Jordan Canonical Form of the following matrix: 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3\\
 0 & 4 & 5\\
 0 & 0 & 4\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I am trying to determine the Jordan Basis first. For that purpose I am trying to find out the generalized Eigenvectors of this matrix.

Corresponding to $1$, Let $U_1$ be the generalized eigenspace. My calculations show that $$U_1=span\{(1,0,0)^t\}$$ and $U_2$ be the corresponding generalized eigenspace for $4$. I found out $$U_2=span\{(1,0,-9)^t,(0,1,6)^t\}$$All I need to do now is find the Jordan basis. Since $(A-\lambda_i I)|_{U_i  }$ is nilpotent, all I need to do is find the basis for each such $i$.

I am confused from here on what to take as the jordan basis. I am sure that $(1,0,0)^t$ will feature as the first column. I am not sure about the other two.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Is $U_2$ an eigenspace? In other words, are all elements of $U_2$ eigenvectors, or is that true only for a $1$d subspace of $U_2$?

Comment: It is a generalized eigenspace. All the elements are not necessarily eigen vectors

Comment: Compute the simple Eigenspace of $4$ call it $E_4$, then determine if it is equal to $U_2$ or if it is only $1$ dimensional (it turns out that it is actually just $1$ dimensional). Then take the vector (of the two you found) which lies in $U_4 \setminus E_4$, call it $v$. Your Jordan Basis will then be of the form $e_1,(A-4I)v,v$ (the $e_1$ coming from $U_1$).
The Jordan Normal Form is then $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Why does the order matter?? I took the basis to be $\{e_1,v,(A-4I)v\}$ and it didn't work out

Comment: If you take them (the vectors corresponding to each single Jordan Block) in the other direction, the Jordan Normal Form will be the transpose (lower triangular)

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Yes, that's true, but the point of my question is that whether all of the elements are eigenvalues or not affects the Jordan form of the matrix.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the Jordan basis.  You can easily find that the eigenspace $E_4$ is one-dimensional, which shows that there is one Jordan block for $\lambda=4$, and the Jordan form is as given in the comment by b00n heT.

Comment: @Travis Had all the elements been eigenvalues , then the matrix would have been diagonalizable. So it does affect the jordan form of the matrix.

Comment: @David I think $E_4$ is two dimensional.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Yes, that's precisely what I'm saying, and precisely why I gave the hint in my first comment.

Comment: @Travis,Oh!!!!!!! I see now.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam No, the eigenspace is one-dimensional - see my answer.  Note: I didn't say the **generalised eigenspace** is one-dimensional, it is indeed two-dimensional.  But this does not determine the Jordan form because it only tells you that the total size of the blocks for $\lambda=4$ is $2$, it could still be a single block or two $1\times1$ blocks.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam I just found a large number of typos in my previous comment and have fixed them, perhaps you need to read it again.  Sorry ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First compute 
\begin{align*}
A-4\,I &= \begin{bmatrix}-3&2&3\\ 0&0&5\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix} &
(A-4\,I)^2 &= \begin{bmatrix}9&-6&1\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix} &
(A-4\,I)^3 &= \begin{bmatrix}-27&18&-3\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
so $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}$
\begin{align*}
\rank\left(A-4\,I\right) &=2 &
\rank\left((A-4\,I)^2\right) &=1 &
\rank\left((A-4\,I)^3\right) &=1 
\end{align*}

This tells us that the smallest value of $k$ so that $\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}\null\left((A-4\,I)^k\right)\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}$ stabilizes is $k=2$. This is called the *index of nilpotency* for the eigenvalue $\lambda=4$.

Now, note that
$$
\null\left(A-4\,I\right)=\Span\left\{
v_1=
\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
We wish to extend this basis for $\null\left(A-4\,I\right)$ to a basis $\left\{v_1,v_2\right\}$ for $\null\left((A-4\,I)^2\right)$ such that $(A-4\,I)v_2=v_1$. That is, $v_2$ must satisfy
\begin{align*}
(A-4\,I)^2 v_2 &= \vec 0 & (A-4\,I)v_2 &= v_1
\end{align*}
One checks that 
$$
v_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1/15\\0\\3/5\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies these equations.

Hence our Jordan form is $A=PJP^{-1}$ where
\begin{align*}
P&=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1/15\\0&3&0\\ 0&0&3/5\end{bmatrix} &
J&=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&4&1\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: This is exactly the procedure I wanted to follow. I was confused over taking the basis elements since the the generalized eigenspace has dimension $2$. Thanks

Comment: Short cut: as $\lambda=4$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ and geometric multiplicity $1$, you can say in advance that the kernels will stabilise at $(A-4I)^2$, and you don't need to spend any effort calculating $(A-4I)^3$.  Not that's it's very much effort ;-)

Comment: @David True, though I wanted to give some insight into the general procedure.

Answer (score 5):

To find $E_4$ we have
$$A-4I=\pmatrix{-3&2&3\cr 0&0&5\cr0&0&0\cr}\ ,$$
which is already in echelon form; the solution is
$$x_3=0\ ,\quad x_2=t\ ,\quad x_1=\tfrac23t\ ,$$
so the eigenspace
$$E_4=\left\{t\pmatrix{\tfrac23\cr1\cr0\cr}\ \bigg|\ t\in{\Bbb R}\right\}$$
is one-dimensional.  So the Jordan basis vectors will form one chain for $\lambda=4$, and (obviously) one chain for $\lambda=1$.  So there is one Jordan block for each eigenvalue, and a Jordan form is
$$J=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&4&1\cr0&0&4\cr}\ .$$